# Awesome WM shortcut to toggle or make a window sticky. This shortcut is not show in my Super+S help menu

Tags: awesome-wm

Trying to find the shortcut to toggle or make a window Sticky in awesome wm. I have not seen any shortcut for this function mentioned in the help menu (Super + S). Any help is appreciated..
[image]

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

There is no key combination for "toggle sticky" in the default config. At least going to https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/blob/master/awesomerc.lua and searching for `sticky` only finds the titlebar icon entry thingie.

To build your own, you could copy the key binding for `ontop` and change it accordingly:
https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/blob/9b1246af3da71910e84cd446e1b973b384ce0fac/awesomerc.lua#L432-L433

```lua
        awful.key({ modkey,           }, "t",      function (c) c.ontop = not c.ontop            end,
                {description = "toggle keep on top", group = "client"}),
```

becomes...

```lua
        awful.key({ modkey,           }, "t",      function (c) c.sticky = not c.sticky            end,
                {description = "toggle sticky", group = "client"}),
```

(Of course, mod4+t is already taken, so you have to pick something else)